# How could I refresh (or detect an expired) active directory oauth2 token in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, oauth, active-directory

I am using azure active directory integration with an MVC application.  So users get redirected to the azure login portal to enter their credentials.  My application has many ajax requests which will not work when the authentication token is expired because the MVC application tries to redirect the API call to the AD login page.

When i refresh the page, any API requests will start to work again.  I was wondering how I can detect on the client side when a session expires or how I can handle refreshing a token with API calls.

Comment: The token should contain information about expiration: expires. Another indication is when Not Authorized is returned. Does the token contain a refresh token?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to renew session by adding a hidden iframe in Layout.cshtml, which hits the new "forced" sign in route at regular time intervals (In sign in operation you could acquire a new access token
).

Please refer to article [controlling a Web App’s session duration](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2016/07/25/controlling-a-web-apps-session-duration-2/)  . In that article you could find a code sample about how to  ensure that app’s session lasts as long as the IdP session(or at least approximate it) in ASP.NET MVC .